# How select dynamic string SQL result by OPENROWSET or SomeFunction in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My expected query:

```sql
with cte as 
(
    select 'select 1 + 2' tSql 
    union all
    select 'select 1 * 2' tSql
)
select somefunction(tsql) as val
from cte
```

Result :

```
val
3
2
```

I tried to do this using:

1. Use OPENROWSET:

I use `OPENROWSET` can get dynamic string SQL result

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;','select 1+2') --result : 3
```

but I get this SQL error

> Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "(local)" does not contain the table tSql. The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

```sql
with cte as 
(
    select 'select 1 + 2' tSql 
    union all
    select 'select 1 * 2' tSql
)
select (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;',tSql)) as val
from cte
```

I check the msdn doc get the problem point is:

[image]

2.Use `sp_executesql`:

```sql
create function F_SqlToNumeric(@sql nvarchar(max))
returns numeric(20,8) as 
begin
    declare @v numeric(20,8);
    select @sql = N'select @v_out = ('+@sql+')';
    exec sp_executesql @sql,N'@v_out numeric(20,8) output',@v_out = @v output
    return @v
end;
```

```sql
with cte as 
(
    select 'select 1 + 2' tSql 
    union all
    select 'select 1 * 2' tSql
)
select F_SqlToNumeric(tSql) as val
from cte
```

I get error :

> Error 557 , Only functions and extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

Comment: `error 557 , Only functions and extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.` it means you can't use dynamic sql within a function. It is not supported

Comment: yes , it looks like no way to do it